# How to extract sub data out of arrays

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using SIMPLE HTML DOM Scraper in PHP trying to get some statistics for various sports teams

index.php

```
$html = file_get_html("https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/trends/ats_trends/");

foreach($html->find("tbody tr") as $h){
    $rows[] = $h->text();
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Green Bay 4-0-0 100.0% 12.8 +10.9 [1] => LA Chargers 4-1-0 80.0% -3.0 -0.1 [2] => Seattle 4-1-0 80.0% 6.8 +2.9 [3] => Pittsburgh 3-1-0 75.0% 7.8 +2.0
```

What im trying to get out of this is the team, followed by stats, for example index 0 would almost have 5 sub array indexs.

```
[0] = green bay
[1] = 4-0-0
[2] = 100%
[3] = 12.8
[4] = +10.9
```

You can see there are multiple elements in the main array where I would need to do this. What is the best way, or should I be doing it a different way with the scraper?

Comment: It looks like these are just strings. So if you explode() them using the space character as the separator, you should get what you need I think.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone better than my answer, I didn't go look at the actual page being scraped/didn't infer the obvious table cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `->children()` which would be the `td`'s then loop over them to get `->text()`, could use a foreach or array_map etc.

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html("https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/trends/ats_trends/");

$rows = [];
foreach($html->find("tbody tr") as $tr) {
    $rows[] = array_map(function($td) {
        return trim($td->text());
    }, $tr->children());
}

print_r($rows);

/**
 * Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green Bay
            [1] => 4-0-0
            [2] => 100.0%
            [3] => 12.8
            [4] => +10.9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => LA Chargers
            [1] => 4-1-0
            [2] => 80.0%
            [3] => -3.0
            [4] => -0.1
        )
 */
```

Comment: Wow thank you, this is exactly what I was wanting. Now my next challenge is getting that data. Would I just do a foreach($rows as $row){
$team = $row[0];}

Comment: np thanks for accept, it would be like `foreach($rows as $team) { // do somthing with $team[0] which would be Green Bay, $team[1] would be 4-0-0 }`